# Are private keys generated by OpenSSL when FIPS mode is disabled usable when FIPS mode is enabled?

Tags: openssl

I am running into an incompatibility between keys generated by OpenSSL while running with FIPS mode disabled, and trying to use those keys with FIPS mode enabled.

OpenSSL version = OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

Command used to create the key (FIPS mode disabled):

```
openssl genrsa -rand <path to rand file> -aes256 -passout file:<path to password file> -out <path to output .key.pem file> 4096
```

Command trying to use the key (FIPS mode enabled):

```
openssl ca -config <path to cnf file> -extensions v3_usr_cert -passin file:<path to password file> -batch -notext -in <path to CSR file> -out <path to output .cert.pem file>
```

The 'default_md' in the cnf file is set to SHA256,
(in both the '[ CA_default ]' and '[ req ]' sections)

The 'private_key' in the cnf file is set to the key generated above

The error I receive is:

```
unable to load CA private key
139772432762696:error:060800A3:digital envelope routines:EVP_DigestInit_ex:disabled for fips:digest.c:251:
```

Is there a different way I should be generating the key to make it compatible when FIPS is disabled, and when FIPS is enabled?

Is there a different way I should be using the key to sign the request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`genrsa` writes OpenSSL's 'traditional' format -- the one with PEM label `RSA PRIVATE KEY` and added headers `Proc-Type` and `DEK-Info`. This uses OpenSSL's (really SSLeay's) nonstandard key derivation (`EVP_BytesToKey`) based on MD5, which is not FIPS approved. (And also isn't very secure, but that's a different question, and has already been asked or answered many times, probably more on security.SX than here.)

You can *generate* a key in 'new' (since ~2000!) PKCS8 format using `genpkey` (which is much more capable, but thus has more options) or you can *convert* the old format with either

```
openssl pkey -in tradfile -passin whatever -aes256 -out pkcs8file -passout whatever
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -in tradfile -passin whatever -v2 aes-256-cbc -out pkcs8file -passout whatever
```

Either of these uses PBES2 and (thus) PBKDF2 with default HMAC-SHA1, which is okay for FIPS. (Technically `pkey` wasn't available before 1.0.0, but if there was a FIPS version of 0.9.x, which I don't recall, it must have expired. And not that it helps you today, but AIUI 3.0.0, which finally started beta about a month ago, will have FIPS in the normal build, not requiring all the extra steps.)

FYI `default_md` in `[req]` is for the signature on the CSR (or with `-x509` selfsigned cert) and in `[CA_default]` similarly is for the signature on the certificate by `ca` -- e.g. you get RSAwithSHA256 versus RSAwithSHA1. It has nothing to do with any keyfile, and only `req` even can generate a key, `ca` cannot.

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085. This was super helpful.

Unfortunately, but as expected, I couldn't run either of those commands while FIPS mode was enabled. They both worked fine once I disabled FIPS mode (which itself is a pain).

I also have a related question. My two commands worked perfectly if run with FIPS disabled. But they also worked perfectly if FIPS was enabled. So `openssl rsa` must run differently in FIPS mode. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Looks like I can answer my related question. With FIPS disabled the keys have `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY` as the header. With FIPS enabled the keys have `BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY`. So `openssl genrsa` definitely wrks differently, though I don't think the user has any control over that difference.

Comment: Right; `BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY` is PKCS8 which supports, and OpenSSL uses, PBES2/PBKDF2 which is okay. The older commands -- both `genrsa` and `rsa` -- normally write trad, but in FIPS mode trad isn't allowed so they are switched to PKCS8 somehow (although I don't see it in the source).